# Temporizador While em Python

Tags: python, loop

Como fazer um temporizador em while? Gostaria de executar um while, e fazer alguma coisa, por ex. um

```
print "hello"
```

ficar executando print "hello" durante 1 hora por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
import time

end_time = time.time() + 10
countTimer = 0
sleepTime = 0.500
while time.time() < end_time:
    time.sleep(sleepTime)
    countTimer += sleepTime
    print('hello, ja passaram {} secs'.format(countTimer))
```

Troque o 10 por 3600 para uma 1hora. Pode retirar o sleep, mas o programa vai ficar muito pesado

Comment: Perfeito Miguel, bem isso mesmo! E se eu quisesse mostrar que isso estivesse sendo executado? Executando o código acima não dá pra perceber na tela que está sendo printado hello conforme o tempo passa, devido ao fato de não mudar nada. Digamos algo assim: passou 500ms ele mostra um: já se passaram 500ms. Como daria para fazer?

Comment: Ha ok vou fazer isso, percebi

Comment: Feito em cima @Allan

Comment: Show de bola Miguel, incrível kra ;-) parabéns!

Comment: De nada @Allan. obgado